# Grid ColumnDefinition star-width is stretching beyond the parent container's bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, .net-4.0

I've designed a grid row as being another grid with a 20/80 split between two columns, with the one on the left having a min width of 250:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue" />
    </Grid>
```

At widths greater than 1250, this works as expected, but as soon as I shrink below that, the first column stops shrinking (as it should) because it has hit 250, but the second column keeps shrinking at the same rate as it did before (rather than collapsing at the same rate of the surrounding window). The result is that a portion of the content is cut out, even though the grid is set to stretch to its container:

[image]

Why isn't the blue frame resizing to fit within its parent container the way other star width columns do? Why has setting a min width broken this all of the sudden?

---

Update: I've rebuilt my entire UI in a sample window (by simply replacing each section's contents with a border), and am unable to reproduce the issue:

[image]

It it possible that the contents (which aren't encountering any MinWidth constraints and seem to be resizing properly as well, albeit too slowly like their parent grid columns) are still somehow impacting the grid columns? What about the fact that the original is in a UserControl and this is in a Window?

Comment: Hi. Put your code inside a Window and it worked ok (as expected) for me.

Comment: Possible workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340233/columndefinition-minwidth-doesnt-work-correctly

Comment: @NestorArturo You're right, I'll add more of my parent container code until I see where the glitch appears and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize - given the information in the original question, it was impossible to answer this question.

Unfortunately for me the problem is a bug in the implementation of the Xceed DataGridControl. By simply replacing each DataGridControl with a border or other control in my original UI, all elements are resized as they should be.

The problem was not that the DataGridControls were encountering their own size constraints. They were in fact continuing to resize themselves as the window resized but they were getting it wrong. My guess is that their implementation relies on walking up the hierarchy or parent UI elements and sizing themselves in accordance to what they calculate their available space to be. I found that nothing short of dictating the exact width of one of the parent elements solves this. If the parent elements use star sizing, and these widths are constrained by column definitions to have a maximum or minimum width or height, the Xceed DataGridControl is oblivious and incorrectly requests a size greater than or less than what is available, even if it's been told to stretch to fit its parent control.

The only workaround I found that doesn't involve boycotting Xceed (which is very tempting) is to redesign the layout so that the first column doesn't grow with the rest of the window and is simply fixed at its minimum width:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue" />
    </Grid>
```

It looks odd and disproportionately squished on large resolution screens, but any attempt to constrain the width while auto-sizing it leads to the behaviour described.

Answer (score 0):

That is totally correct.
In your definition you define that the first columns width has to be at least 250. So 1* has to be at least 250 too. Your second columns width has to be the value of your first column multiplicated by 4. Sorry for my bad english, i hope you can understand.
I cant find an easy and fast solution for that. Maybe you have to bind the MaxWidht property of the second column to the ActualWidth property of the grid and than reduce that value by 250.

Comment: That's not how star width works. The intended behaviour can be seen working in a sample project in the OP.